# How can server push some info to MVC client

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, server

Suppose if i have to run two jobs that are dependent, I can start the second job only after completion of first job, so once the server completes first job it need to push the status to client that he can run and the second job runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebSocket

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Use the SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend() method to send messages.

Spring Security 4 has some new features for WebSocket as well.

If using Tomcat, you'll need at least version 7.0.52